# How to convert DTO to entity without placing business logic in a converter class?

Tags: java, spring, oop, design-patterns

My entity:

```
class Voucher {
  Order order;
  Country country;
}
```

My DTO:

```
class VoucherDTO {
  Long orderId;
  String countryCode;
}
```

The problem is that you cannot inject the repository into the converter - this is wrong. Then what to do with this id and code?

The converter class implements the `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter<S, T>` interface.

Comment: A converter isn't enough. You'll need a service class that presumably creates a new voucher or updates a voucher based on the DTO.

Comment: Please expand on why injecting the repository into the converter is wrong.